# Firefox plugin to block sites

Tags: gratis, firefox

I want to block [skeptics.stackexchange.com](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) in Firefox.

Must have:

- when that part is in the URL, display a message that the site is blocked.

Ideally:

- from other sites (e.g. this one in the hot topics list) remove all links that point there and remove the text that's on the link.

I do not want a standalone webfilter (separate application).

I have tried:

- Adblock Plus. It seems to work for the hot network question list, but does not work for the site itself.

Comment: `0.0.0.0 skeptics.stackexchange.com` entry to the `hosts` list is not what you're looking for, no?

Comment: @Izzy: close, yes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when that part is in the URL, display a message that the site is blocked

[LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) does this.

> from other sites (e.g. this one in the hot topics list) remove all links that point there and remove the text that's on the link.

If you want to remove Skeptics links but keep all other Hot Network Questions, you'll probably need to write a little Greasemonkey script. If you'd be okay with hiding Hot Network Questions altogether, though, that can be accomplished with a CSS one-liner using e.g. Stylish. The CSS code is `#hot-network-questions {display: hidden}`.

Comment: Seems I need LeechBlock NG, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock-ng/